# Japanese ji versus dji and zu versus dzu (pronunciation and keyboard input issue)

Tags: phonetics, ipa, japanese

I have found the following partial hiragana chart on t he internet. I was wondering, in IPA, how does ji (じ) differ from dji and zu (ず) differ from dzu? Technically, how are these pronounced? Thanks.

Also, with a Japanese input keyboard for Android, how do I enter the latter characters (those prefixed with a 'd' in the picture)?

[image: partial hiragana chart]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between these four is the topic of the article on [yotsugana (四つ仮名)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yotsugana). In south Shikoku, they appear to be all different. However, in standard Tokyo Japanese, じ = ぢ and ず = づ.

The actual diachronic change of [dz] to [z] is variable in standard Japanese. According to "[The Sounds of Japanese](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Hos-XSzQ87AC)", the affricate [dz] occurs at the beginning of a word or immediately following a syllable-final consonant, and the fricative [z] occurs in the middle immediately following a vowel. This isn't affected by which kana is used to transcribe it. The kana じ and ず are more common anyway since the gendai kanazukai (現代仮名遣い) post-WW2.

As for Rōmaji input, I've always used t + u / s + i with dakuten.